# Could not find the defined object before use it in match case in scale

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

```
sealed trait Json {
  def toStringT: String=
    this match {
      case JsTrue => "true"
      case JsFalse => "false"
      case JsNull => "null"
      case JsString(str) => str
      case JsNumber(num) => num.toString
      case JsArrayEmpty => "[]"
      case JsArrayT(head, tial) => s"[${head.toStringT}, ${tial.toStringT}]"
      case JsObjectEmpty => "{}"
      case JsObjectT(pair, tail) => s"${pair.key}: ${pair.value.toStringT} \n ${tail.toStringT}"
    }
}


sealed trait JsArray extends Json
//jsarray
case object JsArrayEmpty extends JsArray
final case class JsArrayT(head:Json, tail:JsArray) extends JsArray

final case class JsString(str:String) extends Json
final case class JsNumber(num:Double) extends Json
case object JsTrue extends Json
case object JsFalse extends Json
case object JsNull extends Json


sealed trait JsObject extends Json
// jsobject
case object JsObjectEmpty extends JsObject
final case class JsPair(key:String, value:Json) {
  def toStringT :String =
    key + ":" + value.toStringT
}
final case class JsObjectT(pair:JsPair, tail:JsObject) extends JsObject
```

the compiler complains:

> C:\Users\name\IdeaProjects\HelloWorld\src\Hell5.sc:4:12
> not found:
> value JsTrue case JsTrue => "true"

I could not move the definition of `JsTrue` before `json` definition cause it use the definition of `json`

Comment: Can't reproduce https://scastie.scala-lang.org/YkDF124FQgGCr8fHlZs37Q

Comment: It's something with how you compile/run your code. Try to replace Scala script `*.sc` with ordinary `*.scala`.

Comment: OK, seems like it could not be run in worksheet

Comment: it's because of worksheet works like interpreter and it compiles code line by line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using an `sc` script rather than a full scala file, statements are evaluated one by one. In a normal scala file this will just work.